# Why do I get syntax error in aroma-config even though it seems good after all?

Tags: android

I'm new to this platform, and apologize if I do something wrong here.
Straight to the point, I got Syntax error on Line 3 Column 36 in aroma-config while trying to flash.
Here is what I am doing in its config:

## aroma-config

```
# Dedicated to the all mighty Bandi Chod
##################################################
ini_set("force_colorspace", "rgba");
ini_set("transition", "stack");
ini_set("rom_name",             "a30 mod menu");
ini_set("rom_version",          "for any oneui rom");
ini_set("rom_author",           "jtin");
ini_set("rom_device",           "a30");
ini_set("rom_date",             "27.07.2077");

# Show splash screen
splash(2000, "coolest_splash");
fontresload( "0", "ttf/regular.ttf", "12" );
fontresload( "1", "ttf/bold.ttf", "16" );
theme("modern_blue");

###############################################
#ROM INFORMATION
###############################################
ini_set("text_next", "Next ");
viewbox(
    "mods",
    "<@center>Welcome to the installation wizard!</@>\n\n" +
    "<@center>Thank you for trying out this mod, This is combination mods for A30.</@>\n\n\n\n" +
    "<@center>Tap <b>'next'</b> to continue.</@>",
    "@welcome_logo"
);

###############################################
#INSTALLATION TYPE
###############################################
ini_set("text_next", " ");
ini_set("icon_next", "@none");
menubox(
    "Installation",
    "<b>Select your Install Method</b>",
    "@install",
    "configs.prop",

    "Express Install",          "This takes the hassle out of installation by intuitively configuring your system with a click, ensuring a seamless and hassle-free setup experience.",    "@install_express",
    "Personalized Install",     "This allows users to tailor the software or operating system setup according to their specific preferences and requirements.",    "@install_custom",
    "Installation Tuner",       "This process allows ROM modification without requiring a reinstallation, while removed apps cannot be restored.",       "@install_tune"
);
# Express install
if prop("configs.prop","selected") == "1" then
    include("install_express.edify");
else
    include("install_custom.edify");
endif;

###############################################
#CSC
###############################################
ini_set("text_next", " ");
ini_set("icon_next", "@none");
menubox(
    "CSC Selection",
    "<b>Select your Region</b>",
    "@earth",
    "csc.prop",

    "OLE",   "Indonesia XID",        "@ido",
    "ODM",   "South Asia:- INS BKD NPB SLK BKD",         "@ins",
    "OLM",   "East Asia:- CAM LAO MYM XSA THL XME XSP XTC XXV",         "@vie",
    "OWO",   "South America:- ARO BVO CHO COO EON GTO MXO PEO TPA UPO UYO ZTA ZTM ZTO ZVV",       "@zto",
    "OJM",   "Middle East:- ACR AFR ECT ILO MID PAK SRR TUN XSG AFG DKR EGY KSA MWD TKD TUR BTC FWD ILP LYS XFA XFE XFV",        "@tur",
    "OXM",   "Rest of the world:- 3IE AMO ATL ATO AUT AVF BGL BOG BTB BTE BTU CAC CAU CNX COA COS CPW CRO CYV DBT DCO DRE DTM EUR EUX EUY EVR FTM H3G HTS HUI ITV LUX MAX MBC MBM MEO MET MOB MOT MSR NEE O2C O2U OMN OPV ORO ORS ORX PHE PHN PLS PRT ROM SEB SEE SEK SER SFR SIM SIO SKZ SWC TCL TIM TMH TMS TMZ TOP TPH TPL TRG TSI VD2 VDC VDF VDH VDI VGR VIP VOD XEC XEF XEH XEO XEZ",        "@rus",
    "Skip CSC",  "Will not change CSC", "@skip"
);

###############################################
#CHANGELOG
###############################################
ini_set("text_next", "Next ");
textbox(
    "Mods Changelogs",
    "<b>Mods Changelog</b>",
    "@lic",
    resread("changelog.txt")
);

###############################################
#LICENSE
###############################################
ini_set("text_next", "Install");
agreebox(
    "Terms & Agreement",
    "<b>Read The Terms Of Use Carefully!</b>",
    "@lic",
    resread("agreement.txt"),
    "I Agree with these Terms and Conditions",
    "<@center>You must accept the terms and conditions</@>"
);

###############################################
#INSTALL
###############################################
ini_set("text_next", "Exit");
setvar("retstatus",
  install(
      "Installation:",
      "<b>Flashing the mods, it should take only few seconds or not over 5 minutes.</b>\n"+
      "<b>Please wait...</b>",
      "@installer",
      "Installation finished!"
  )
);
```

Well as I look for the error, it seems normal, because semicolon (;) is needed as always. But it just target on the semicolon. Any idea? I would appreciate for the help.

1. Modify edify files and some text in aroma-config
2. Zip and flash
3. Getting aroma-config syntax error